# Open external app on Android when button is pressed on React web-app without triggering page refresh

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web-app built with React, TS & Bootstrap CSS. On mobile devices there is a link button component containing a deeplink which will open an external app on the mobile device. When the app is opened, the page should not refresh and the user should be able to re-open the browser and see the same page with the same state as when they left.

This works as expected on iOS Safari; when I click the button, the external app opens and the user can complete their transaction. When the user goes back to the browser, the page is as they left it. This also works on Android with Firefox, DuckDuckGo, Aloha browsers.

However on other Android browsers, the page refreshes in the background as soon as the external app is opened. This happens for Chrome and some other Chromium based browsers I tried; Kiwi, Brave, Samsung Internet, Edge.

My question is if there is anything I can do on the component to avoid the browser refreshing the page when the button is pressed. I could not find any settings to disable this setting in the browsers. I could change the website to make the state persist after a page refresh, but wanted to see if there is any other workaround, or if anyone knows why the browsers refresh like that.

Code for my link button component;

```html
<a
  href={deeplink}
  className="btn btn-primary"
  role="button"
  onClick={handleButtonClick}
>
  Open external app
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to open the link in a new tab using `window.open(url, '_blank');`

I removed the hyperlink and had a button that on click called the below function. The browser would open the deeplink in a new tab, the app receives the deeplink and opens, then the browser closes the new tab and leaves the original page in its original state, without refreshing.

```
const handleButtonClick = () => {
    window.open(challengeData, "_blank");
};
```